# Save tabel tkinter as data frame to do TOPSIS

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, tkinter, input

I am a newbie at Tkinter. I try [this project](https://pythonguides.com/python-tkinter-table-tutorial/), but I want to save the table as data frame because I want to process it more.

```
from tkinter import * from tkinter import ttk
ws=Tk()
ws.title('PythonGuides') ws.geometry('500x500')
set = ttk.Treeview(ws) set.pack()
set['columns']= ('id', 'full_Name','award') set.column("#0", width=0,  stretch=NO) set.column("id",anchor=CENTER, width=80) set.column("full_Name",anchor=CENTER, width=80) set.column("award",anchor=CENTER, width=80)

set.heading("#0",text="",anchor=CENTER) set.heading("id",text="ID",anchor=CENTER) set.heading("full_Name",text="Full_Name",anchor=CENTER) set.heading("award",text="Award",anchor=CENTER)

global count count=0
     for record in data:
      
    set.insert(parent='',index='end',iid = count,text='',values=(record[0],record[1],record[2]))
       
    count += 1



Input_frame = Frame(ws) Input_frame.pack()

id = Label(Input_frame,text="ID") id.grid(row=0,column=0)

full_Name= Label(Input_frame,text="Full_Name") full_Name.grid(row=0,column=1)

award = Label(Input_frame,text="Award") award.grid(row=0,column=2)

id_entry = Entry(Input_frame) id_entry.grid(row=1,column=0)

fullname_entry = Entry(Input_frame) fullname_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)

award_entry = Entry(Input_frame) award_entry.grid(row=1,column=2)

def input_record():
    

    global count
   
    set.insert(parent='',index='end',iid = count,text='',values=(id_entry.get(),fullname_entry.get(),award_entry.get()))
    count += 1

   
    id_entry.delete(0,END)
    fullname_entry.delete(0,END)
    award_entry.delete(0,END)
     
#button Input_button = Button(ws,text = "Input Record",command= input_record)

Input_button.pack()



ws.mainloop()
```

I plan to use it as inputs to do TOPSIS. [Here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hungrybluedev/topsis-implementation/notebook) is the reference for the TOPSIS.
Thanks before.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, here is a community to solve your problem and not a coding service. Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([value for value in [my_game.item(line)['values'] for line in my_game.get_children()]],
                  columns=my_game['columns'])
```